# Trigger shell script if a file has been modified

Tags: sql, oracle, shell, unix

I have created a shell script which basically does 2 function,

1.Loads the data from .csv into table using sql loader.

2.Runs a procedure in oracle DB once the data is loaded.

What i want to know is that if someone populates the .csv file with valid data,i want to trigger the shell script automatically after waiting for 1 minute

Comment: Do you want to check every minute whether the .csv was populated or wait one minute after being populated?

Comment: wait one minute after population of data

Comment: so Basically, you a need a script that triggers your above mentioned script when there is csv files came in a location, right ?

Comment: yes . once data is copied to the CSV file the shell script has to triggered after waiting for 1 or few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

inotifywait should do the trick, and, if you need to wait for a minute insert a "sleep 60" command.

See here: https://superuser.com/questions/181517/how-to-execute-a-command-whenever-a-file-changes